# How do I setsockopt of a TcpStream via libc?

Tags: rust, libc, setsockopt

I know `TcpStream` has `stream.set_read_timeout` but I need to make it in `libc` for Windows, but my code don´t works and I believe it is because I can't understand the way to put milliseconds in `_value: *const c_char`. In Rust I wrote `let qtie = [100].as_ptr();` but its wrong. I also don't know how return a `c_int` in `extern "C" fn`.

```
use std::net::{TcpListener, TcpStream};
use std::io::{Read, Write};
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;

use libc::c_int;
use libc::c_char;

pub unsafe extern "C" fn setsockopt(
    _socket: c_int,
    _nivel: c_int,
    _nombre: c_int,
    _value: *const c_char,
    _option_len: c_int
) -> c_int {return 0;}

fn al_cliente(mut stream: TcpStream) {
    
    const SOL_SOCKET:i32  = 1; // También 0xffff
    const SO_RCVTIMEO:i32 = 20;
    const SO_SNDTIMEO:i32 = 21;
    
    const tam_buff:usize = 10;
    let mut data = [0 as u8; tam_buff];
    
    loop {
        
        println!("{:?}", stream);
        let buska = format!("{:?}", stream);
        let arrsk:Vec<&str> = buska.split(" ").collect();
        
        let socket = arrsk[7].parse::<i32>().unwrap();
        //let socket = 0;
        println!("{}", socket);
        
        let qtie = [100].as_ptr();
        
        // Ejemplo: int nTimeout = 5000; // 5 seconds
        //          setsockopt(socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (const char*)&nTimeout, sizeof(int));
        unsafe { setsockopt(socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, qtie, 10); }
        
        //stream.set_read_timeout(Some(Duration::from_secs(10)));
        let ver = stream.read(&mut data).unwrap();
        
        stream.write(&data[0..tam_buff]).unwrap();
        
        let atexto = String::from_utf8_lossy(&data);
        println!("{:?}", atexto);
    }
}


fn main() {
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("0.0.0.0:3333").unwrap();
    println!("Server listening on port 3333");

    for stream in listener.incoming() {
        
        match stream {
            Ok(stream) => {
                println!("Conectado: {}", stream.peer_addr().unwrap());
                
                let _hilo = thread::spawn(move || {
                    al_cliente(stream);
                });
            }
            Err(e) => {
                println!("Error: {}", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [socket manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html):

> Specify the receiving or sending timeouts until reporting
> an error.  The argument is a struct timeval.

Luckily, the libc crate [defines that structure](https://docs.rs/libc/latest/libc/struct.timeval.html) so you can do this:

```rust
    let sock_timeout = libc::timeval {
        tv_sec: 10,
        tv_usec: 0,
    };

    let result = unsafe {
        libc::setsockopt(
            socket,
            libc::SOL_SOCKET,
            libc::SO_RCVTIMEO,
            &sock_timeout as *const libc::timeval as *const libc::c_void,
            std::mem::size_of::<libc::timeval>() as u32,
        );
    };
```

In order to get the rust reference into a `void *` pointer, you need to cast it twice: once to a pointer to the type, then to the void pointer.

Note that `libc` also defines all the constants you need, so you don't need to define them yourself.

Also don't forget to check the return value from `setsockopt`. It will return 0 for success and -1 for an error. The error code will be available in `errno`, which in rust you can access via [`Error::last_os_error().raw_os_error()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/io/struct.Error.html#method.last_os_error).

Comment: First: THANK YOU VERY MUCH! I had learn a lot from you.

I tried your code suggestion but it didn't work and I'm wondering:
Would what I'm trying to do work the same as "stream.set_read_timeout("?
The real reason for using "C" is because I'm trying to use native::TlsStream and it doesn't have a "settimeout" implementation.

Comment: Do you mean you got an error returned, or it did not time out as you expected? [This](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/library/std/src/sys/unix/net.rs#L337) is how `set_read_timeout` is implemented for Unix, and [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/library/std/src/sys/windows/net.rs#L349) for windows.

Also: if you are trying to set a timeout on the socket being used by NativeTLS on Windows, there might be other APIs that should be used (although I do not know what they are)